# Mobile App Works on iPhone but Not Android

Tags: android, jquery, iphone, mobile

Demo: http://admin.bigblackbag.net/web/mobile_content.asp?WebsiteID=15175&forcemobile=1

Works perfectly on iPhone.. but seems to crash on native Android browser.. it crashes when you try to use the navigation menu and doesn't look adjust properly.. Any ideas? Pretty please!? Been stumped for weeks..

```
$(function () {
var menuStatus;
// Show Menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function () {
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $("#page").animate({
            marginLeft: "85%",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        });
        $("#page").css("position","fixed");
        $("#page").addClass("shadow");            
        $("#menu").animate({opacity: "1"}, 300);
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#page").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        });
        $("#page").css("position","absolute");
        $("#page").removeClass("shadow");
        $("#menu").animate({opacity: "0"}, 300);
        return false;
    }
}); 
 // Menu behaviour
$("#menu li a").click(function () {
    var p = $(this).parent();
    if ($(p).hasClass('active')) {
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
    } else {
        $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
        $(p).addClass('active');
    }
  });   
});
```

Comment: "but seems to crash on native Android browser" what do you mean when you say "crash" I just loaded it up on a device and it seems to load the page fine.

Comment: It's working for me.  Are you click baiting?

Comment: click baiting? i'm referring to the navigation.. it seems to crash the site when loaded and can't be scrolled, as reported by some users when using the native android browser

Comment: @user1427307 it seems to scroll fine on my devices.

Comment: could you test this link please? http://admin.bigblackbag.net/web/mobile_content.asp?WebsiteID=15175&forcemobile=1

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function () {
var menuStatus;
// Show Menu
$("a.showMenu").click(function (e) {
    if (menuStatus != true) {
        $("#page").animate({
            marginLeft: "85%",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = true
        }).css("position","fixed").addClass("shadow");            
        $("#menu").animate({opacity: "1"}, 300);
    } else {
        $("#page").animate({
            marginLeft: "0px",
        }, 300, function () {
            menuStatus = false
        }).css("position","absolute").removeClass("shadow");
        $("#menu").animate({opacity: "0"}, 300);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
}); 
 // Menu behaviour
$("#menu li a").click(function () {
    $("#menu li").removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });   
});
```

Comment: tried, but the main issue is the native scrolling for the navigation on the android, it's unscrollable..